# Static IP address not working through GUI?

Tags: pi-4, ssh, static-ip

I used [this](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/static-ip-raspberry-pi) tutorial to make my Raspberry Pi 4B a static IP address. However, every time I run

```
arp -a
```

on my Windows machine, I see the Pi's IP address as dynamic. I'm not sure if it's better to change it using the command line and editing the dhcpcd.conf file but I tried that as well and got nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" posting a link rather than explaining what YOU did

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Comment: by far the least troublesome and least susceptible to errors that can lock you out of a headless pi ... reserve an IP in the DHCP server (commonly your main router) which I believe is mentioned in the link above

Comment: Please explain ***why*** you are assigning a static IP instead of using a dynamic address? In other words, what is it that you cannot do with a dynamic address that you can do with a static address?

Comment: means you have a static IP on your raspberry and it is shown as dynamically learned on your windows PC?  That's normal. Feel free to read more about the arp protocol.